# Render Quality Doesn't Change

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

this my first time modeling a object from scratch. im using blender's latest version on steam. but i have a problem about render image. whatever I do the render quilty isn't changing. i increased samples, added denoise etc but it didn't effect anything. it always has a weird fuzziness on it. (and the second problem i discovered the rendered image in viewport looking much better.) what should i do?

[image: weird texture]

Comment: I don’t think that’s a render problem per se. It appears to be intentional displacement on the bottle from a texture, or possibly systematically bad geometry. Zoom in on it and see if it stays the same size. Show a wireframe, and see if it lines up with anything. Swap materials around, and see if it changes.

Comment: You say it’s invisible in the viewport. Are you sure you’re in viewpoint render, or just material preview?

Comment: nope i don't think so. bcause the bottle has a label on it and it pixelated too

Comment: To me, that looks like Z-fighting. Any chance you have a second object that is hidden in the viewport? Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders unless they are _disabled_.

Comment: If you want a solution to your problem, you could provide a blend file on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can figure it out. The image and description alone may not be enough for us to identify the cause.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you so much! Its fixed now, I wish I knew it was that easy! I didn't know blender renders hidden objects. I was created a backup mesh of my bottle and it turns out it is the reason of overlapping.

Comment: @UtkuB. Glad it's fixed :). if no one else has posted this as an answer for you, when some  time  has passed, you can answer your own post and mark it as accepted, to clear it up